# Problem with a ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I don't understand the following error:

```
Activity [myActivity] has leaked window
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4050c3f8 that was
originally added here
```

Here is my code:

```
private ProgressDialog progression;
private Handler handler;
private Thread thread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Conteneur général
    ui = new RelativeLayout(this);

    progression = ProgressDialog.show(this, "SwissParl", "Init", true);
    handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            progression.dismiss();
        }
    };

    thread = new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            firstMethod();

            SecondOne();

            andTheLast();

            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };

    thread.start();
    setContentView(ui);
}
```

Apparently, the problem is on the line where I instanciate my ProgressDialog...

Any idea?

Comment: what if you put `setContentView` first, after `super.onCreate`?

Answer (score 1):

That happens normally when the activity is destroyed when showing a dialog, for example rotation or finishing activities while showing dialogs.

Try adding a dismiss dialog onPause of activity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but i suggest you use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Something like this

```
private class MyBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ParentActivity.this);


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {

        firstMethod();
        SecondOne();
        andTheLast();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //dialog.setCancelable(false); //depending...
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

To execute it, call `new MyBackgroundTask().execute()` inside `onCreate()`

It's far cleaner than using a handler,thread combination...

Comment: That's a good idea, but there is a problem with the second line.. It tells me ParentActivity cannot be solved to a type. (I putted this class in my MainActivity)

Comment: @Greg, Obviously, i meant, Replace `ParentActivity` with your parent activity which is `MainActivity`....

Answer (score 0):

```
private ProgressDialog progression;
private Handler handler;
private Thread thread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Conteneur général
    ui = new RelativeLayout(this);
    setContentView(ui);


    progression = ProgressDialog.show(this, "SwissParl", "Init", true);
    handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            progression.dismiss();
        }
    };

    thread = new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            firstMethod();

            SecondOne();

            andTheLast();

            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}
```

You are trying to show a `ProgressDialog` before adding the main view to the activity.Use the `setContentView` before you start the `ProgressDialog`